# Non-blocking signal handlers in Gtkmm

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtkmm

For the `Gtkmm` application I'm making, when a row in a `ListBoxRow` is selected, the callback needs to start a while-loop which will run indefinitely. Let's say the while-loop ends when a particular variable is set to false.

The problem with this, is that my current handler (when it starts the while-loop) completely blocks the main thread, hence blocking any interaction with the GUI.

I think I can use threads to solve this (e.g. start a new thread from the handler, and start the while-loop in the thread), but I foresee problems with this such as:

- Multiple threads will be able to be created (by selecting more than 1 row, not at the same time but while another thread is running), so how will I store these threads?
- If I store the threads in a vector object, how will I know which thread to join to the main thread, and when to join it?

I'm thinking this must be a fairly common problem, so does `Gtkmm` or anything else provide a method of perhaps running the handler as a non-blocking function, or something to that effect?

Comment: You are correctly foreseeing the potential problems, and it is up to you to figure out how to solve them for your application. There is no universal answer to something like this, because it closely depends on the nature of the application and how it works. To correctly answer your question, by yourself, you need to have a good grasp of concurrency and multi-threaded programming. If you don't know yet, now is an excellent opportunity for you to invest some time into studying this topic.

Comment: Do you need to know in the main thread when the other thread finishes ? if no the join is useless

Comment: @bruno I do not. Why does this make the join useless?

Comment: @JacobGarby the goal of the _join_ is to wait for the other thread ending, if you don't need to know that why do you call _join_ ?

Comment: @bruno I never thought about it like that... I guess you're right

Comment: @JacobGarby C++ provides a concept for [_promises_ and _futures_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) you should lookup these, when you want to handle stuff asynchonously.

Comment: "the callback needs to start a while-loop which will run indefinitely" What should the loop do, apart from running indefinitely?